# How to convert a LinqExpression into OData query URI

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, odata

There are a lot of answers on how to convert ODataQuery into an Expression or into a Lambda, but what I need is quite the opposite, how to get from a Linq Expression the OData query string.
Basically what I want is to transcend the query to another service. For example, having 2 services, where your first service is not persisting anything and your second service is the one that will return the data from a database. Service1 sends the same odata request to Service2 and it can add more parameters to the original odata request to Service2

[image]

**What I would like:**

```
    public IActionResult GetWeatherForecast([FromServices] IWeatherForcastService weatherForcastService)
    {
        //IQueryable here
        var summaries = weatherForcastService.GetSummariesIQ();
        var url = OdataMagicHelper.ConvertToUri(summaries);
        var data = RestClient2.Get(url);
        return data;
     }
```

Comment: Are you using an OData Client framework? If so then this is usually automatic if they implement a linq provider. It might help to show some code around your scenario

Comment: Imaging you are using an odata query to execute a simple select * from your table using linq on your backend, now get that IQueryable and turn it into a uri odata link as a string, that is what I am looking for

Comment: It helps if you provide an example linq expression that you want to convert to OData, rather than us all responding with arbitrary examples that might not help.

Comment: Oh snap, so from the server, you want to return the OData string? That's vastly different from what I was going to provide as a solution, but still do-able I guess. Can I ask why? Given that you could just return the data from this endpoint itself

Comment: @ChrisSchaller it is to know if it is doable, at the end of the day, OData works with a grammar that converts the query string into an abstract syntax tree that can go both ways, normally they transform the query into an Expression. On the other hand is for integration purposes, for example, Graph API uses OData syntax to query different OData APIs and sometimes you need to reuse the same query and put extra parameters on top to send it to other APIs. I can collect the information from the same controller and build it manually but I would like to know if it can be done easily

Comment: I just want to confirm, are trying to generate this string on the server or on the client?

Comment: You haven't actually demonstrated a linq query that you want to convert ;). Did you have something more complex in mind?

Comment: @ChrisSchaller any parameter that you can pass in a single OData query will generate a LINQ expression, I just put the select to demonstrate the SQL statement, but imaging passing $orderby or $filter that will be translated to a where clause in LINQ and in SQL.

Comment: It's just redundant to serve a URL for a specific resource to the client when the client can easily use linq to build their own scoping query. In other words the server shouldn't be telling the client the specific query operators to use, the server can define defaults, but its up to each individual client to decide how to query the resources they need. I think you should re-evaluate why you want this because there are better strategies you can use from the client.

Comment: @ChrisSchaller I update the question again so it is more clear now I guess, thanks for the help

Comment: I see, there are different architectural strategies to simplify that... Ideally (in OData) any  _fringe_ or _edge_ services should be acting as clients to the internal service or they should be very lightweight wrappers that mostly pass through the original client request. We usually avoid this pattern using EF as the _internal_ service, so not deploying `Service2` as a separate deployed asset at all.

Comment: Given the new expected method, if that method already has the data, why do you want to return the data from the `RestClient2`, why wouldn't you query that service and return the result, its strange to _get `GetSummariesIQ` from the local runtime_, then **throw away the data**, then get the data again _from a different service_. It can be done, but it is not very efficient, will be hard to maintain and I strongly advise you to re-think the structure into something far simpler.

Answer (score 0):

> *OP Clarified the request: generate OData query URLs from within the API itself.*

Usually, the queries are so specific or simple, that it's not really necessary to try and generate OData urls from within the service, the whole point of the service configuration is to publish how the client could call anything, so it's a little bit redundant or counter-intuitive to return complex resource query URLs from within the service itself.

We can use [Simple.OData.Client](https://github.com/simple-odata-client/Simple.OData.Client) to *build* OData urls:

If the URL that we want to generate is:

```
{service2}/api/v1/weather_forecast?$select=Description
```

Then you could use Simple.OData.Client:

```
string service2Url = "http://localhost:11111/api/v1/";
var client = new ODataClient(service2Url);
var url = await client.For("weather_forecast")
                      .Select("Description")  
                      .GetCommandTextAsync();
```

---

### Background, for client-side solutions

> If your OData service is a *client* for another OData Service, then this advice is still relevant

For full linq support you should be using [OData Connected Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/connectedservice/getting-started) or [Simple.OData.Client](https://github.com/simple-odata-client/Simple.OData.Client). You could roll your own, or use other derivatives of these two but why go to all that effort to re-create another wheel.

> One of the main drivers for a *OData Standard Compliant API* is that the meta data is published in a standard format that clients can inspect and can generate consistent code and or dynamic queries to interact with the service.

#### How to choose:

- **Simple.OData.Client** provides a lightweight framework for dynamically querying and submitting data to OData APIs. If you already have classes that model the structure of the API then you can use typed linq style query syntax, if you do not have a strongly typed model but you do know the structure of the API, then you can use either the untyped or dynamic expression syntax to query the API.

  > If you do not need full compile-time validation of your queries or you already have the classes that represent the resources served by the API then this is a simple enough interface to use.

  This library is perfect for use *inside* your API logic if you have need of generating complex URLs in a strongly typed style of code without trying to generate a context to manage the connectivity to the server.

  > **NOTE:** Simple.OData.Client is sometimes less practical when developing against a large API that is rapidly evolving or that does not have a strict versioned route policy. If the API changes you will need to diligently refactor your code to match and will have to rely on extensive regression testing.
- **OData Connected Services** follows a pattern where some or all of the API is modelled in the client with strongly typed *client side proxy* interfaces. These are POCO classes that have the structure necessary to send to and receive data from the server.

  > The major benefit to this method is that the POCO structures, requests and responses are validated against the schema of the API. This effectively gives you full intellisense support for the API and allows you to explor it's structure, the generated code becomes your documentation. It also gives you compile time checking and runtime safety.

  The general development workflow after the API is deployed or updated is:

  1. Download the [`$metadata`](https://www.odata.org/blog/queryable-odata-metadata/) document
  2. Select the Operations and Types from the API that you want to model
  3. Generate classes to represent the selected DTO Types as defined in the document, so all the inputs and outputs.
  4. Now you can start using the code.

  In VS 2022/19/17 the *[Connected Services](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/generating-http-api-clients-using-visual-studio-connected-services/)* interface provides a simple wizard for establishing the initial connection and for updating (or re-generating) when you need to.

  > The OData Connected Service or other *client side proxy* generation pattern suits projects under these criteria:
  >
  > - The API definition is relatively stable
  > - The API definition is in a state of flux
  > - You consume many endpoints
  > - You don't want to manually code the types to serialize or deserialze payloads

  Full disclosure, I prefer the connected service approach, but I have my own generation scripts. However if you are trying to generate OData query urls from inside your API, its not really an option, it creates a messy recursive dependency... just don't go there.

Connected services is the low-(manual)-code and lazy approach that is perfect for a stable API, generate once and never do it again. But the Connected Service architecture is perfect for a rapidly changing API because it will manage the minute changes to the classes for you, you just need to update your client side proxy classes more frequently.